# How to use the value of a Published object?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am having an array say "arr" of type "TestObject" in the class "TestClass". I do have the "arr" as Published.
Now the object of "TestClass" is "xyz".

Now if I want to fetch the value as well as listen to change. How do I do it?

I am using this:

```
xyz.$arr.map { value in }
```

But I want to use the value as a normal value, but it is of type Published<[TestObject]>.Publisher.Output

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `sink` the value but you have to establish a strong reference to the subscriber.

```
@State private var subscription : AnyCancellable?

...

subscription = xyz.$arr.sink { array in
    array.map { value in }
}
```

Comment: I have to subscribe within the class. So in that case State cannot be used. So I have to use normal variable. Right?

Comment: Yes, `@State` is for a `view`.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Vadian :)